# Get reCAPTCHA from third party website using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, python-requests

I was just working on various things and I was curious if it was possible if you could:

Get a reCAPTCHA from a URL --> Show just the reCAPTCHA in Python --> Once user has solved it, grab the reCAPTCHA response and make it a variable.

I've been working on various ways to do this but I'm not sure how I could get just the iframe and display it. Any ideas? Thanks.